# Routing .htaccess to GitHub

Tags: php, javascript, git, .htaccess, github

I was wondering if there was a way to basically host a site on your server so you can run PHP, but have the actual code hosted on GitHub. In other words...

If a HTTP request went to:
http://mysite.com/docs.html

It'd request and pull in the content (via `file_get_contents()` or something):
https://raw.github.com/OscarGodson/Core.js/master/docs.html

Or, if they went to:
http://mysite.com/somedir/another/core.js

It'd pull down:
https://raw.github.com/OscarGodson/Core.js/master/somedir/another/core.js

I know GitHub has their own DNS servers, but id rather host it on my so i can run server side code. What would the htaccess code look like for this?

Comment: What would be the benefit of doing that ? Why not just clone your git repository on your server ?

Comment: Is there a PHP script or something for that? Im asking because i just dislike dealing with FTP and it's almost entirely for client sites which are on shared servers where i dont have SSH access. So i figured I could upload this reusable htaccess file and point it to the right repo and then I can just make changes via Git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is beyond the capabilities of .htaccess files, if the requirement is to run the PHP embedded in the HTML stored on github.com at the server on yourserver.com simply by a configuration line like a redirect in the .htaccess file.

A .htaccess file is typically used to provide directives to the Apache web server.  These directives can indicate, for example, access permissions, popup password protection, linkages between URLs and the server's file system, handlers for certain types of files when fetched by the server before delivery to the browser, and redirects from one URL to another URL.

An .htaccess file can issue redirects for http://mysite.com/somedir/another/core.js to https://raw.github.com.... but then the browser will be pointed to raw.github.com, not mysite.com. Tricks can be done with frames to make this redirection less transparent to the human at the browser... but these dont affect the fact that the data comes from github.com without ever going to the server at mysite.com

In particular, PHP tags embedded in the HTML on github.com are never received by mysite.com's server and therefore will not run.  Probably not want you want.  Unless some big changes have occurred in Apache,  .htaccess files will not set up that workflow. It might be possible for some expert to write an apache module to do it, but I am not sure.

What you can do is put a cron job on mysite.com that git pull's from github.com every few minutes.  Perhaps that is what you want to do instead?

Comment: Awh, thanks a lot. Hmm, yeah... is there a way to setup a cron job that waits for a change from another site? So, if i make a change I dont have to wait an hour for it to change on the other server? I'm a JavaScript guy, so sorry for the n00b like questions. I know how to do this all with JS, but then it's not indexable but search engines :\

Comment: Nope, you just run the cron job more often.... like every 5 min or every 2 min.  If you are on shared hosting, there may be a limit.

Comment: Git has a server-hooks feature where you can write a shell script that runs when a git push arrives.  This is useful if you set up git on your own server, and then use "git push" at your workstation to push to it.

Answer (score 1):

If the server can run PHP code, you *can* do this.

Basically, in the .htaccess file you use a RewriteRule to send all paths to a PHP script on your server. For example, a request for `/somedir/anotherdir/core.js` becomes `/my-script.php/somedir/anotherdir/core.js`. This is how a lot of app frameworks operate. When my-script.php runs the "real" path is in the PATH_INFO variable.

From that point the script could then fetch the file from GitHub. If it was HTML or JavaScript or an image, it could just pass it along to the client. (To do things properly, though, you'll want to pass along all the right headers, too, like ETag and Last-Modified and then also check those files, so that caching works properly and you don't spend a lot of time transferring files that don't need to be transferred again and again. Otherwise your site will be really slow.)

If the file is a PHP file, you could download it locally, then `include` it into the script in order to execute it. In this case, though, you need to make sure that every PHP file is self-contained, because you don't know which files have been fetched from GitHub yet, so if one file includes another you need to make sure the files dependent on the first file are downloaded, too. And the files dependent on those files, also.

So, in short, the .htaccess part of this is really simple, it's just a single RewriteRule. The complexity is in the PHP script that fetches files from GitHub. And if you just do the simplest thing possible, your site might not work, or it will work but *really painfully slowly*. And if you do a ton of genius level work on that script, you could make it run OK.

Now, what is the goal here? To save yourself the trouble of logging into the server and typing `git pull` to update the server files? I hope I've convinced you that trying to fetch files on demand from GitHub will be *even more trouble* than that.

Comment: No, i dont have SSH access to most of my client's sites because they are usually on shared hosting. I dont want to remember 100s of FTP user/pass either and i hate having to use Git, push to GitHub, then copy and paste the file onto their server. I'd rather upload a PHP script, set a var to "x" repo then whenever they request an update/change i can just push to GitHub

Comment: If you MUST use FTP, I would keep a clean git checkout somewhere, and when you need to deploy, do a `git pull` and then use an app that will sync the local dir to the server over FTP (just skip the `.git` directory). And if you can, convince your clients to switch to a shared host like NearlyFreeSpeech.NET, which supports SSH and is reliable and cheap. Once you have SSH, you can use git push or rsync or dozens of other, better tools.